# A PostgreSQL query with 'ANY' is not working

Tags: arrays, postgresql

```
SELECT "Ticket_id"  FROM "Tickets"
 WHERE "Status" = 1 AND ("Ticket_id" !=  ANY(array[1,2,3])) Limit 6
```

And the result is 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You want to use `ALL`, not `ANY`. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486):

> **9.21.3. ANY/SOME (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> ```
>
> [...] The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given ***operator***, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ANY` is "true" if any true result is obtained.

So if we say this:

```
1 != any(array[1,2])
```

then we'll get true since `(1 != 1) or (1 != 2)` is true. `ANY` is essentially an `OR` operator. For example:

```
=> select id from (values (1),(2),(3)) as t(id) where id != any(array[1,2]);
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

If we look at [`ALL`, we see](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18509):

> **9.21.4. ALL (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ALL (array expression)
> ```
>
> [...] The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given ***operator***, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ALL` is "true" if all comparisons yield true...

so if we say this:

```
1 != all(array[1,2])
```

then we'll get false since `(1 != 1) and (1 != 2)` is false and we see that `ALL` is essentially an `AND` operator. For example:

```
=> select id from (values (1),(2),(3)) as t(id) where id != all(array[1,2]);
 id 
----
  3
(1 row)
```

If you want to exclude all values in an array, use `ALL`:

```
select "Ticket_id"
from "Tickets"
where "Status" = 1
  and "Ticket_id" != all(array[1,2,3])
limit 6
```

Comment: 'ANY' is essentially 'OR'; 'ALL' is essentially 'AND' - very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean:

```
"Ticked_id" NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: I don't know the value of the array. I have to use ANY

Comment: Oh my bad, that changes everything - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10675636/1406230 above is good :)

Comment: NOT IN (SUBQUERY) [has performance issues in certain cases](https://www.percona.com/blog/sql-optimizations-in-postgresql-in-vs-exists-vs-any-all-vs-join/). `EXISTS`, `<> ALL` or `JOINS` are preferred.